# SimplePie: Autoloader.php opening stream

Tags: simplepie

Good afternoon, using Simplepie to load RSS feeds onto my site.  Godaddy hosted site, with a WP blog for the RSS feed.  Have read through Simplepie docs, and searched forums, but can't seem to figure this out.  I'm wondering if my folder permissions aren't correct for the ../cache folder?

Error MSG:

Warning: require_once(../php/autoloader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\12074013\html\test.php on line 15

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../php/autoloader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Hosting\12074013\html\test.php on line 15

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not permissions on the cache directory, it's likely a problem with how you set up the SimplePie directories or your include statement.

The file you are running is in `D:\Hosting\12074013\html\test.php`

and it's trying to include the `autoloader.php` file, which the include

```
require_once(../php/autoloader.php)
```

thinks is in `D:\Hosting\12074013\php`, which is below the web root. Check your install path and set the include to the correct directory path.